# Angular SVG Map to add click event does not work

Tags: css, angular, typescript, svg

I have added my Angular Bootstrap 5 project to SVG World map. I have some issue; I want to add this to the click event, and when the user goes to every following region to Mouse pointer hover and showing popup model

- #North America section
- #South America section
- #Africa section
- #Europe section
- #Asia section
- #Australia section

Here is the my code:

**[StackBlitz is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1e1kkf?file=src%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.css)**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: @core114, the stackblitz example doesn't seem to work

Comment: There are multiple projects utilizing bootstrap 5 behaviour in angular, like ngx-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap, mdboostrap.. The question needs to be more specific

Comment: Add a click handler on the SVG then use [MDN ElementsFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint) to filter the path you clicked

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: The last half of the first paragraph is incomprehensible. Can you fix it?